# Looking for a override of SafeBuffer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I was reading Katz's [Safe Buffer](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/) article while trying to upgrade our side to Rails 3.  We have a lot of helpers that build up fairly complex html/css bits from data we know is safe (we're doing things like large menus).

Unfortunately - if I'm reading Katz's article right - it seems like you need to mark everything html_safe or you get escaped.

I'm wondering if anyone has come up with a simple hack to turn this functionality off on a module/method/block level yet?  I was looking at the code in Rails that does this and it doesn't look all the trivial to override.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a couple "easy" solutions:

1. Modify the helpers by hand so that they return `html_safe`'d strings
2. Iterate over the methods (module?) and use `alias` to alias them to, say, `_unsafe_helper_name`, and then have `helper_name` return `_unsafe_helper_name.html_safe`
3. Use the `raw` method in your views. Calling `raw` on output turns off Rails 3's built in protection and outputs the string just as it is with no escaping.